# how to get the url after click to know whether it has 404 error or downloaded the file in the preferenced place using selenium Firefox python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, webdriver

I am new to web automation using selenium Firefox python environment.

Step 1:- I am hitting a webpage using driver.get. there by I am setting up my preference to download the file in the specific location.

Step2:- Providing data to Decal Number after finding driver.find_element_by_id("DecalNumber"). And click Begin search button.

Step3:- Now again click button by accessing through xpath.

Step4:- Now again click one more button by accessing through xpath. this will open a file in new window (https://www.tdlr.texas.gov/DownLoadableContent/Elevator/Images/1197897/26695455.tif) as an example.

My questions are all follows:-

1. Since the file is automatically getting saved in the preferenced location, and most of the time I get 404 error no data found and some of the time I get .tiff image data. how do I check whether it as data or 404 error????
2. If 404 error is not found, then need to rename the file that is being downloaded with its associated Decal Number using Shutil library. but the problem here is, if I have 404 error then no new file is getting downloaded. But shutil.move() is tryin to rename the file which is already downloaded for other decal number. Shutil is trying to change the file name wit current decal number, which should not supposed to do. how to stop this happening?

Any lead are welcome.

```
from selenium import webdriver
# create webdriver object
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference('browser.download.dir', r'C:\Users\Swaminathan Sekar\Documents\Decal_Final')
fp.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
fp.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', "image/tiff")
fp.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
fp.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile', "image/tiff")
fp.set_preference('browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force', False)
fp.set_preference('browser.download.manager.useWindow', False)
fp.set_preference('browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting', False)
fp.set_preference('browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen', False)
fp.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete', False)
fp.set_preference('browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone', False)
fp.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(fp)
driver.maximize_window() 
driver.implicitly_wait(20)

driver.get("https://www.tdlr.texas.gov/Elevator_SearchApp/Elevator/Search")
window_before = driver.current_window_handle
Decal_test=Decal_Number[75:76]

for i in range(0,len(Decal_test)):
    inputElement1 = driver.find_element_by_id("DecalNumber")
    inputElement1.clear()
    inputElement1.send_keys(Decal_test[i])
    driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/form/div[6]/div/div[2]/button")[0].click()
    driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/a[1]")[0].click()
    driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td/button")[0].click()
    window_after = driver.window_handles[1]
    driver.switch_to.window(window_after)
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.refresh()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[text()='Subsequent Inspection']/preceding-sibling::td[1]/a").click()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element(".tiff"))
    print(driver.current_url)
    time.sleep(20)
    driver.switch_to.window(window_before)
    driver.back()
    driver.back()
    Initial_path= r'C:\Users\Swaminathan Sekar\Documents\Decal_Final'
    filename = max([Initial_path + "\\" + f for f in os.listdir(Initial_path)],key=os.path.getctime,default=0)
    if filename !=0:
        shutil.move(filename,os.path.join(Initial_path, str(i)+'_'+str(Decal_test[i]) + ".tiff"))
print('Elasped time =',time.process_time(),'s')
```

Comment: to get response codes you'll need to access the network requests. Look into BrowserMob Proxy with selenium to capture statuses.

Comment: @DMart:- To capture the status of file being downloaded or not ?.  how about for Question 2 ?? Any suggestion you would like to give?

Comment: @DMart :- how to get network access here??